# Create function calls to returned functions parser in PyParsing

Tags: python, recursion, pyparsing, recursive-regex

I want to parse function calls that can call functions 'returned' by other functions:

```
thisReturnsFunction()()
```

I have done this:

```
id = Regex(r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*')

funcal = Forward()

value = funcal | id

funcal << value + Literal("(").suppress() + Literal(")").suppress()
```

Accidentally, Python stack overflows and the whole Python crashes.
I know that the `value` is recursive and matches infinitely `thisReturnsFunction("Hello!")`, because the `funcal` is matching, because the `value` is mathing, because the `funcal` is matching...

How to avoid that and design valid pattern??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that Pyparsing can parse high-order function in 'pure' way. But there are some 'hacky' way: create token for function, add handler for the token and make correct syntax structure inside the handler.
Example (I also add tokens for function arguments)

```py
from pyparsing import Forward, Literal, Regex, OneOrMore, Optional, Group, delimitedList

def function_parser(s, loc, toks):
    if len(toks) <= 2:
        return [toks[0], list(toks[1])]
    else:
        return [function_parser(s, loc, toks[:len(toks)-1]), toks[-1]]

id = Regex(r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*')
comma = Literal(',')
funcal = Forward()
expression  =  funcal | id 
function_args = Optional(Group(delimitedList(expression,comma)),[])
funcal << id + OneOrMore(Literal("(").suppress() + function_args + Literal(")").suppress())

funcal.setParseAction(function_parser)

def test_print(string):
    l = funcal.parseString(string).asList()
    print(l)

test_print('justFunction(arg)')
test_print('justFunction(arg)',)
test_print('thisReturnsFunction()()',)
test_print('thisReturnsFunction(arg1, arg2)(arg3)')
```

It produces:

```
['justFunction', ['arg']]
['justFunction', ['arg']]
[['thisReturnsFunction', []], []]
[['thisReturnsFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']], ['arg3']]
```